# stripe: No such external account but the external account do exist

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I create an account in stripe under `test` module by stripe api. And bind a bank account with this account. Go to `Stripe dashboard -> connect -> accounts`, I could see the account which I created. Click it and to see the detail, I could see the external accounts:

[image]

but when I want to create a payout to this bank account:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payouts    \
     -u sk_test_*********:   \  
     -d amount=400     \
     -d currency=usd    \
     -d destination=ba_1CrVQnJziGn15h8UAvSlEUfI    \
     -d source_type=bank_account
```

It gives me error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such external account: ba_1CrVQnJziGn15h8UAvSlEUfI",
    "param": "destination",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
 }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the solution for this?

Comment: @BHARATGUPTA finally I changed to Stripe Express Account. Easy to manage and implement

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct code to do this.

When trying to list payouts on a connected account, you have to make the API request authenticating as this account so in addition to the destination bank account ID you need to pass the stripe account ID.

```
payouts = Stripe::Payout.list(
  {:destination => external_account},
  {:stripe_account => "acct_XXXXXX"},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#regular-payouts), in order to create Payouts for connected accounts you must specify the connected account on the request:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payouts \
  -u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
  -H "Stripe-Account: {{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}" \
  -d amount=1000 \
  -d currency=usd
```